# Adding existing VMs into OpenShift cluster

Tags: openshift

I have a fleet of "reserved" AWS VMs that I want to add to my OpenShift cluster.  I am able to extend the cluster via autoscaler allocating new VMs, but is it possible to add the existing reserved VMs to the cluster?

I want them to run CoreOS and not RHEL. The cluster runs on RedHat Opeshift 4.8

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible as far as I know. Basically you'll need to do the following:

- Generate the Ignition file (`oc get $(oc get secret -n openshift-machine-api -o name | grep worker) -n openshift-machine-api -o yaml | grep userData | awk ‘{print $2}’ | base64 -d > worker.ign`) and make it available via HTTP somewhere.
- Start your VMs with the CoreOS AMI (see your existing machines for which exact one)
- For the startup, set the kernel parameters (`coreos.inst.install_dev`, `coreos.inst.ignition_url`)
- Once the VM is started, approve the CSR ( `oc get csr`, `oc adm certificate approve`)

You can find the commands with some more details in some blog posts here:

- https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/adding-nodes-outside-of-a-machineset-in-vsphere-ipi-clusters
- https://medium.com/swlh/mixing-vms-and-baremetal-workers-in-a-pre-existing-openshift-4-installed-with-ipi-b401b5617de9

Comment: hm.. I've done this with RHEL before, but CoreOS it's a whole other level. 

For example, I can't just replace the AMI , I'd have to start a new VM . The point of the excersize is to reuse the registration.